# Distorted animated model when exported to FBX

Tags: animation, mesh, rigging, export, .fbx

I've been making some animated rigs with rigify.

All works fine. The problem is, when I export the model with **animations** to **FBX**, the mesh gets crazy distorted in any program I open it afterwards.

I've tried **applying** the **scale** to the armature, exporting the **fbx** object and bvh separately.

(In this last case I get the FBX in t-pose correctly but won't generate any rigs).

Any clue of what's going on? I must be missing something but I can't quite find the issue.

[Blend file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/9ep7x5vybacs57y/standardswing_278.blend?dl=0)

[image: example]

Comment: you check the options before export FBX in the Tools  (left side, bottom) ?

Comment: I had a model that got very distorted. After I removed transforms on a specific bone in the animation the distortions disappeared (my model's arms did not work, but the hands did. The arms were inside the main body so it was not a catastrophe in my case.)